# Is it possible to align a print statement to the center in Python?

Tags: python, alignment, console-output

I was wondering if it was possible to align a print statement in Python (newest version). For example:

```
print ("hello world")
```

would appear on the user's screen on the left side, so can i make it centre-aligned instead?

Thank you so much for your help!

= 80 (column) x 30 ( width)

Comment: Maybe it depend on console

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.center if you know the console's width.

Comment: `print ("{:>30}".format("hello world"))`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, use [`os.get_terminal_size()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.get_terminal_size) function to get the console's width(so you don't need to know your console before):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.get_terminal_size()
os.terminal_size(columns=80, lines=24)
>>> os.get_terminal_size().columns
80
>>> os.get_terminal_size().columns  # after I changed my console's width
97
>>>
```

Then, we can use [`str.center()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center):

```
>>> import os
>>> print("hello world".center(os.get_terminal_size().columns))
                                  hello world                                  
>>>
```

So the clear code looks like:

```
import os

width = os.get_terminal_size().columns
print("hello world".center(width))
```

Comment: If you want to use Python to do that, the answer is **No**. Because Python is running inside the console.

Comment: @KtEwing do you mean specify a console size independently to the real console size ?

Comment: If you want to do that, then I don't know. But that would be very interesting.

Comment: on linux, you can call wmctrl to set the size and position of a terminal window (not a python command, but a separate program, but you could call it with subprocess or something maybe)

Comment: @KtEwing just replace `width = os.get_terminal_size().columns` by `width = 50` or whatever value you want for the width

Comment: Can't figure why this does not work with "\nHello World\n"?

Answer (score 5):

Knowing the console width, you can also print centered using `format`:

```
 # console width is 50 
 print "{: ^50s}".format("foo")
```

will print 'foo' in the middle of a 50-column console.

Comment: In Python 3.6+ you can do this with f-strings: `print(f"{: ^50s}")`