# How to print a multiline string centralised (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the following string in a centralised position in the console, but .center() doesn't seem to work

```
"""             ,      ,
             (.-""-.)
        |\  \/      \/  /|
        | \ / =.  .= \ / |
        \( \   o\/o   / )/
         \_, '-/  \-' ,_/
           v   \__/   v
           \ \__/\__/ /
         ___\ \|--|/ /___
       /`    \      /    `\
"""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center-aligning text on console in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907236/center-aligning-text-on-console-in-python)

Comment: As it is a multiline, you'd prrobably need to do it on every line. Can you show some code?

Comment: Unfortunately not as that is done at the end of a string so I couldn't put it on everyline as its done outside the quotes, and doesn't work on multiline text files apparently, I tried it

Comment: What's your original string?

Comment: You can call `splitlines()` to convert the multiline string into individual lines, which you can then each "center" based on some width

Comment: not sure what you mean crissal

Comment: i just tried that OneCricketeer and I ended up with a deformed version because the same center command doesn't alline all of them properly

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html

Comment: The SO question may answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594958/is-it-possible-to-align-a-print-statement-to-the-center-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your input string you have spaces before your pixel art.
I used also the answer provided in the comments [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64620724/11647025).

```py
import shutil

SIZE = shutil.get_terminal_size()
COLUMNS = SIZE.columns


def tty_center_str(s: str):
    print(s.center(COLUMNS))


def tty_center_multiline(s: str):
    for line in s.splitlines():
        tty_center_str(line.strip())
```

Output:

```
>>> tty_center_multiline(s)
                                    ,      ,                                    
                                    (.-""-.)                                    
                               |\  \/      \/  /|                               
                               | \ / =.  .= \ / |                               
                               \( \   o\/o   / )/                               
                                \_, '-/  \-' ,_/                                
                                  v   \__/   v                                  
                                  \ \__/\__/ /                                  
                                ___\ \|--|/ /___                                
                              /`    \      /    `\
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html